# ¿Por qué me aparece este error en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: parameter was not defined

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
require "conexion.php";
$message = '';

  if (!empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['apellido']) && !empty($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['contraseña']) && !empty($_POST['confirmar_contraseña'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellido, usuario, contraseña) VALUES (:nombre, :apellido, :usuario, :contraseña)";
    $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $_POST['nombre']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':apellido', $_POST['apellido']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':usuario', $_POST['usuario']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':contraseña',$_POST['contraseña']);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {  <============= Aquí me sale el error
      $message = 'Felicidades, su usuario ya está creado';
    } else {
      $message = 'Lo sentimos mucho, hubo un error al crear su usuario. Intente nuevamente';
    }
  }  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

La posible causa de ese error es la letra **Ñ** que estas usando en tu variable contraseña.

- Cambia el **nombre de columna** contraseña en tu base de datos por contrasena.
- Cambia el **nombre del campo** :contraseña por :contrasena
- Cambia el **atributo** name="contraseña" de tu form por name="contrasena".

Es importante que intentes evitar el uso de la letra Ñ para nombres de variables, métodos, etc.