# ¿Por qué me sale el error "Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number"?

Tags: php, html

Tengo el siguiente formulario html

```
                <form action="send.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 contact-form-item wow zoomIn">
                        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre:" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 contact-form-item wow zoomIn">
                        <input name="nombre_empresa" id="nombre_empresa" type="text" placeholder="Nombre de la empresa:" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 contact-form-item wow zoomIn">
                        <input name="correo" id="correo" type="text" placeholder="Correo corporativo:" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 contact-form-item wow zoomIn">
                        <input name="contraseña" id="contraseña" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña:" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 contact-form-item wow zoomIn">
                        <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje:"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 contact-form-item">
                        <button type="submit" class="send_message btn btn-main btn-theme wow fadeInUp">Registrarse</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="error text-align-center" id="err-timedout">Se agotó el tiempo de espera de la conexión con el servidor.</div>
                    <div class="error" id="err-state"></div>
                </form>
```

Y mi codigo php es este:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
 
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$nombre_empresa= $_POST["nombre_empresa"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$contraseña = $_POST["contraseña"];
$mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];
$db=DB::conectar();

        $insert=$db->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES(NULL,:nombre, :nombre_empresa, 
        :correo, :contraseña, :mensaje)');

        $insert->bindParam(':nombre',$nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert->bindParam(':nombre_empresa',$nombre_empresa, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
        $insert->bindParam(':correo',$correo, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
        $insert->bindParam(':contraseña',$contraseña, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
        $insert->bindParam(':mensaje',$mensaje, PDO::PARAM_STR);    
    
        $insert->execute();
        exit;
?>
```

Me sale el siguiente error **"Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\market_studio\send.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\market_studio\send.php(20): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\market_studio\send.php on line 20"**

Investigando vi que la causa es porque el binding no coincide con los nombres de las columnas en la inserción pero yo todo lo veo igual, alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: Es posible que sea por culpa de la letra ñ, prueba a escribir el parámetro :contraseña sin la ñ (ponle una n).

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué me aparece este error en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169787/por-qu%c3%a9-me-aparece-este-error-en-php)

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP si era eso, muchas gracias